# Why isn't \clearfield suppress issue number in footnotes in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

The `\clearfield`command should suppress issue numbers globally in `biblatex`, but in my MWE below, it only suppressed the issue number in the bibliography, and it ghostly reappears in the footnote.  Why is this and how can I suppress the issue number everywhere?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,backend=biber,ibidtracker=true,ibidstyle=lc,giveninits,ecli=true]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{article}{
    \clearfield{issue}%
    \clearfield{number}%
}{}}
\addbibresource{mylibrary.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{mylibrary.bib}
@article{VanderMeulen2013,
author = {van der Meulen, Bernd},
doi = {10.3390/laws2020069},
issn = {2075-471X},
journal = {Laws},
number = {2},
pages = {69--98},
title = {{The Structure of European Food Law}},
volume = {2},
year = {2013}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    A sentence.\autocites{VanderMeulen2013}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: an annoyingly wrong footnote]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\AtEveryBibitem` applies only to the bibliography. If you need your `\clearfield`s to apply to citations as well, you can use `\AtEveryCitekey`. But of course that doubles the lines of code you have to write.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=oscola,
  giveninits,
  ibidtracker=true, ibidstyle=lc,
  ecli=true,
]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{issue}%
     \clearfield{number}}
    {}}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{issue}%
     \clearfield{number}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{VanderMeulen2013,
  author  = {van der Meulen, Bernd},
  doi     = {10.3390/laws2020069},
  issn    = {2075-471X},
  journal = {Laws},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {69--98},
  title   = {The Structure of {European} Food Law},
  volume  = {2},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  A sentence.\autocites{VanderMeulen2013}
    
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

In order to completely remove fields from the output I usually prefer a sourcemap solution that deletes the fields when they are read from the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=oscola,
  giveninits,
  ibidtracker=true, ibidstyle=lc,
  ecli=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
      \step[fieldset=issue, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{VanderMeulen2013,
  author  = {van der Meulen, Bernd},
  doi     = {10.3390/laws2020069},
  issn    = {2075-471X},
  journal = {Laws},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {69--98},
  title   = {The Structure of {European} Food Law},
  volume  = {2},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  A sentence.\autocites{VanderMeulen2013}
    
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: B van der Meulen, ‘The Structure of European Food Law’ (2013) 2 Laws 69.]